# I cannot view the welcome page on Symfony 3.0/2.8/LTS (fresh install)

Tags: symfony

I've been learning Symfony and I used this [page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) as a guide on how to install it.

I installed/fetched various branches:

```
# symfony new testonly27 2.7

# symfony new testonly28 2.8

# symfony new testonly30 3.0

# symfony new testonlylts lts
```

On all instances, I tried viewing the welcome page. **It only works in 2.7.x.**

On 2.8 and LTS, I get this error (different path names of course for 2.8 and LTS):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /opt/www/testonly28/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php on line 62
```

On 3.x, I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /opt/www/testonly30/var/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2094
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you show us file at the line mentioned in error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using PHP <= 5.5.

The [relevant line](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/2.6/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php#L62) in the Doctrine ProxyGenerator is

```
    'baseProxyInterface'   => Proxy::class,
```

The ::class keyword syntax was added in PHP 5.5.

Symfony 3.0 [requires PHP >= 5.5.9](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html).

Symfony 2.8 claims to [require PHP 5.3.9](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/requirements.html), but somehow, the version of Doctrine you've pulled in requires 5.5 as well, so that's why it's not working for you either.

Comment: The issue is that the archive that is downloaded when using the Symfony installer is built on a PHP 5.5 platform thus pulling in newer versions of several Doctrine packages. When using older PHP versions, running `composer update` after performing the installation should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install php >= v5.5 since what it complains about is `Proxy::class`, which was introduced in 5.5